Setting execute permission on ftp only for owner with Nautilus
I have connected to sftp server using Nautilus (i.e. Other Locations from standard Files window).
I want to add x permission but only for owner. When I click Properties and Permissions - the GUI offers me only one global checkbox "Allow executing file as program". It assign x permission to Owner/Group/Others globally. Is that any trick to set it only for Owner?

Current version of Files does not have this ability. See What happened to dconf/Nautilus "show-advanced-permissions" in 13.04?
The way do it is to set it in the terminal with chmod u+x file_name
